# Hair appears different from viewport rendering preview and actual rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, hair

[image]

Above is the viewport render preview.
Below is the actual render.
I would like the render to look like the viewport render.
I've matched the viewport display and render options to be identical, so they'd appear the same but it's not. What the heck is the problem here?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the bangs specifically, the number of child particles in "single hairs" is set to 10 for Viewport but 100 for Render. Simply set both to 10 instead:

[image]

And here's what you're looking for (fantastic hair, btw):
[image]
Hope this helps! Peace and God bless!